# Debug PHP With Xdebug in Netbeans and via FTP

Tags: php, debugging, ftp, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have a PHP application that runs on a Debian server where I've installed apache 2.2.4 and xdebug.

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.2
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

All the PHP files are saved on this server. The Server IP is : 192.168.0.2

The problem is that I'm opening the PHP project via FTP with Netbeans on a Windows 7 environment where apache is NOT installed!

Is it possible to debug in this scenario and does someone have any links for direction how to configure this scenario?

Please any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is documented. xDebug allows to connect to a remote IDE. For that you certainly do _not_ need some http server installed on that remote system. However what you _do_ need is network access _from server to client_, since it is the server (xDebug) initiating the communication. That is a non-trivial requirement. Are you sure this is given for your setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found a solution.

These links helped me:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

http://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+netbeans+xdebug+configuration

The xdebug.ini i modified like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.103
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

The IP adress 103 is the adress of my local machine and i had to add the idekey to the ini.

Comment: These two links i add because i can't post more than two links at the moment [http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html]

[http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html]